# I have recently created a GUI using a .hta file I want to run a powershell script I wrote. I can't correct this error

Tags: javascript, powershell, user-interface, hta

I get this error:
[image: Error message I receive]

I can not find what is actually the problem from my limited knowledge everything looks correct

Here is the code I am using:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Application Executer</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION ID="oMyApp" 
        APPLICATIONNAME="Application Executer" 
        BORDER="yes"
        CAPTION="no"
        SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
        SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
        SYSMENU="yes"
        SCROLL="yes"
        WINDOWSTATE="normal">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function RunFile() {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("C:Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Apps\Clean_Teams.ps1", 1, false);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<br>
<center>
<input type="button" value="Clean Teams" onclick="RunFile();"/>
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Clean Chrome" onclick="RunFile();"/>
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Clean Edge" onclick="RunFile();"/>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You cannot run `.ps1` files directly; you must invoke them via the the PowerShell CLI ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to run `powershell.exe` with the appropriate parameters. Below is an example HTA for launching PowerShell scripts that demonstrates one way to set up the correct command line. Also note that `X-UA-Compatible` is set to `IE=9`. Without any declaration, the HTA will default to `IE=5` mode.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Script Selector</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
<hta:application
  id=oHTA
  icon=Powershell.exe
>
<script>
Visible=1;
NoWait = false;
w = 640;
h = 480;
oWSH = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell");
window.resizeTo(w, h);
window.moveTo((screen.availWidth - w)/2, (screen.availHeight - h)/2);

function RunScript(ScriptName) {
  if (db.checked) { x = "-NoExit"} else {x = ""}
  CmdLine = 'Powershell.exe ' + x + ' -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "' + ScriptName + '"';
  oWSH.Run(CmdLine,Visible,NoWait);
}

</script>
<style>
body  {background-color:LemonChiffon; font-family:Segoe UI; font-size:11pt}
br {font-size: 16pt} 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input id=db type=checkbox>Debug (check to keep PowerShell console open)<br>
<input id=b1 type=button value="PowerShell Script 1.ps1" onclick=RunScript(b1.value)><br>
<input id=b2 type=button value="PowerShell Script 2.ps1" onclick=RunScript(b2.value)><br>
<input id=b3 type=button value="PowerShell Script 3.ps1" onclick=RunScript(b3.value)><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much since this is my first question. I understand better with your explanation. I will try these suggestions shortly and let all know the results. Thank you again

Comment: @KennyOBrien So, what were your results?